# Active directory locking user out after one attempt

Tags: windows, active-directory

The DC is set up to lock out after three failures however this particular member that has some different applications is getting locked out after one failure.  Any ideas what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: A question about some configuration error (like misinterpreting the result code) causing the appliation to try to bind more than once, locking the account, is out of topic for StackOverflow. Try your luck with logs and more details at [SF].

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when the user has logged on to another device with their credentials then changed their password. Now the other device/service is trying to log on/run with the old cached credentials. This has happened to me a few times before because I have tasks running on multiple servers under my credentials and after changing my password (90 days) I forgot to change them on the other machines. Try having the user log out or shut off all devices they have used then reset their credentials. That worked for me. Microsoft also has [tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738772%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to figure out where these credentials are being used.

Comment: Thank you I am going to give this a try!